# How to delete files and create a log file of the deleted content?

Tags: python, automation

I have written a script in a Python which will delete the files with a particular extension from a particular directory. But I want to know whatever files are deleted their names should be stored in a log file or .txt file.

For e.g. I have a file `a.log` and `b.log` in the location `'C:\SampleFolder'` and I'm deleting both files from this folder using the following script. So their name `'a.log'` and `'b.log'` should be stored in a `'delete.log'` file with the date and time.

What kind of modifications do I have to do in my code or which function or library should I have to use for this purpose?

```
import os, time, sys

folder_path = "C:\SampleFolder"
file_ends_with = ".log"
how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove = 7

now = time.time()
only_files = []

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_full_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_full_path) and file.endswith(file_ends_with):
        #Delete files older than x days
        if os.stat(file_full_path).st_mtime < now - how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove * 86400: 
             os.remove(file_full_path)
             print "\n File Removed : " , file_full_path
```

Comment: Each deleted file has its name in `file` (was well as `file_full_path`) inside the `for` loop. `os.stat()` has its timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a log handler to your program and then instead of printing your message you would just log it and it would have all the necessary info and come with all the logging support which may be useful for any future modifications you make to your code.

```py
import logging.handlers
import logging

handler = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler("/path/to/storage/file/my_app.log")

# define format of the log, in this case just a date & time with the log message
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(message)s")

# attach new formratter
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# get logger instance and update its settings
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel("INFO")
logger.addHandler(handler)

# now just log away
logging.info("File deleted: {}".format("your_file.log"))
```

You can add the above snippet to your program and log what you need from there - it will be written to the file you specified. For more on logging, read the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).